# AVPlayerLayer says always nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avplayerlayer

I don't understand why it is not working. I pass a videoURL trough a segue to a another ViewController. This works fine.

In the other ViewController I want to play the video. But for some reason it is not working. 
I unwrap the URL with optional binding. But playerLayer does not accept the URL. It says always nil.

This is the URL: VideoURL Optional(file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/517BA864-F5CB-4E2C-BE54-D42555569266/Documents/3d.mov)

My code:

```
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
var videoURL: URL?


    func playVideo() {

    if let _videoURL = videoURL {
        player = AVPlayer(url: _videoURL)

        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(layer: player!)

        playerLayer?.frame = contentView.layer.bounds

        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)

        player?.play()
    }
```

Comment: You probably don't unwrap the String that you give in videoURL initializator..

Comment: the player has a value, but the playerLayer does not accept the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset) and an [AVPlayerItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem). Then pass that `AVPlayerItem` into the `AVPlayer` rather than trying to use the URL init.

I tested this with a sample video I downloaded from [here](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-video-files/sample-mov-files-download/). Note there is no sound in this video.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let videoUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file_example_MOV_1920_2_2MB", withExtension: "mov")!
    private var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?
    private var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playVideo()
    }

    func playVideo() {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl)
        let primaryPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: primaryPlayerItem)

        let videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoLayer.frame = view.bounds

        view.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        videoPlayer = player
        playerLayer = videoLayer
        videoPlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. It's working.

```
var player: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

func playVideo() {
     if let url = videoURL {
    do {
        let item:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player                = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        playerLayer           = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame     = contentView.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    } catch {
        print("Error1", error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what the problem on my old code was?

Comment: Why are you using a `do` block when you have no `try` calls? "'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block"

Comment: @adri567 You dint pass your local file url path in AVPlayerItem. Because  an AVPlayerItem stores a reference to an AVAsset object, which represents the media to be played.